# What is the meaning of "prove $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$" in this question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

There is a math problem:

> If $a+b=c+d$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ prove $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$

So by the $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$,Which statement should I prove?

First:  ($a=c$ and $b=d$) or ($a=d$ and $b=c)$

Second: $a=c$ and $b=d$

I think I should prove the first statement because of properties of the sets but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, it should be the first statement.

Comment: Yes: it's the first statement.

Comment: Thank you guys I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is intended; the second would use $()$ instead of $\{\}$. If $a=d\ne c=b$ then $a+b=c+d,\,a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, so the second interpretation is false.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you need to prove that the sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ are equal.

The first statement is correct since order is irrevelant in sets.